# Как понять и решить задание нормализации числа с плавающей точкой?

Tags: математика, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Есть такое задание в книге Structured Computer Organization в Appendix B. Floating-point numbers:

> **4**. The following binary floating-point numbers consist of a sign bit, an excess 64, radix 2 exponent, and a 16-bit fraction. Normalize them.
>
> a. 0 1000000 0001010100000001
>   b. 0 0111111 0000001111111111
>   c. 0 1000011 1000000000000000

#### Мое решение

Я понимаю это задание так:

У нас есть следующий формат: 1 бит знака, 7 бит экспоненты, со смещением 64 и 16-битная мантисса.

Нам нужно нормализовать число 0 1000000 0001010100000001, представленное в этом формате. Число называется нормализованным, если крайний левый бит его мантиссы — это 1. Значит нам нужно сдвинуть все биты мантиссы влево на 3 бита. Если мы сдвигаем число влево на три бита, значит умножаем его на 2³. Следовательно, чтобы число не изменилось, нам нужно уменьшить экспоненту на 3.

Если исходное число (0 1000000 0001010100000001) в десятичный вид, то получим:

```
+ 2^(64 - 64) × (2^(-4) + 2^(-6) + 2^(-8) + 2^(-16)) = +1 × 0.0820465087890625 = +0.0820465087890625
```

Если перевести это же число, нормализованное мной, (0 0111101 1010100000001000), то получим:

```
+ 2^(61 - 64) × (2^(-1) + 2^(-3) + 2^(-5) + 2^(-13)) = +2^(-3) × 0.6563720703125 = 0.125 × 0.6563720703125 = +0.0820465087890625
```

Т. е. то же самое число.

#### Решение автора книги

Решения нашел [здесь](http://unina.stidue.net/Calcolatori%20Elettronici%202/Materiale/Andrew%20S.%20Tanenbaum%20-%20Structured%20Computer%20Organization%205th%20Edition%20-%20Solutions%20Manual.pdf). Я так понимаю, это официальные ответы, представленные издательством.

> **4**. To normalize, shift left 1 bit at a time, adding 1 to the exponent at each step, until the leftmost bit of the fraction is 1. The results are
>
> (a) 0 1000011 1010100000001000
>   (b) 0 1000101 1111111111000000
>   (c) 0 1000011 1000000000000000
>
> The third one is already normalized.

#### Решение @avp

Из-за расхождения в моем ответе и ответе автора, решил попросить помощи в [чате C, C++](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26298/c-c):

> …я понимаю этот пример по другому. Задан знак 0 -- положительное, экспонента -- 1000000 == 0x40 == 64 (т.е. с учетом смещения 64 это 0) и 16-разрядное целое 0x1501 == 5377.
>   Вот его и надо переводить в дробь
>
> @eanmos вообще, ваш взгляд на задачу наверное более правильный (вычесть 3 из экспоненты). В моей интерпретации сама формулировка задачи выглядит слишком вычурно. И ответ (ответов в книге я не нашел) в моей интерпретации будет -- прибавить к экспоненте 12 (поскольку 5377 надо для перевода в дробь делить на 4096), что явно не совпадает с ответом о котором вы спрашиваете.
>
> — @avp

Так какой ответ правильный? Как правильно решить это задание?

Comment: Ваше решение правильное. Но достаточно ли Вам для успокоения мнения нескольких человек? :-)

Comment: Я же говорю, издательства нередко ошибаются, может и сам профессор ошибся, никто не безупречен. Из той же книги: To normalize, shift the fraction left 11 bits and __subtract__ 11 from the exponent. И это согласуется и с вашим решением и с тем, как записываются числа в `IEEE 754`

Comment: @extrn, оформите, как ответ, пожалуйста, я приму)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо того, чтобы дублировать ответ из комментариев, немного распишу, как было бы представлено в `IEEE 754` (Double precision) вышеупомянутое число

> 0.0820465087890625

В двоичном представлении без какого-либо дополнительного кодирования это число выглядит так:

> 0.0001010100000001<sub>2</sub>

Что соответсвует нормализованному виду

> 1.010100000001<sub>2</sub> × 2<sup>-4</sup>

тип `double` содержит такие битовые поля

```
1 бит   - Знак
11 бит  - Порядок (со смещением 1023)
52 бита - Мантисса (дробная ee часть)
```

Целая часть мантиссы не записывается в память, дело в том, что числа в `IEEE 754` (почти) всегда записываются в нормализованном виде, а значит перед точкой подразумевается единица.

Итого получаем:

> Знак: 0<sub>2</sub>
>
> Порядок: -4 + 1023 = 01111111011<sub>2</sub>
>
> Мантисса: 0101000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000<sub>2</sub>

Проверить это можно, например, в `python`

```py
import struct

value = 0b0_01111111011_0101000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000

print(struct.unpack('d', struct.pack('q', value))) # (0.0820465087890625,)
```

Так что единственная отличие от вашего решения в том, что порядок на единицу меньше.